# Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, uicollectionviewlayout, swift2, nscopying

I'm using this [Custom Collection View Layout](https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout) implementation.  I'm able to run the example in that repo just fine, but when I copy the `CustomCollectionViewLayout.swift` into my own project, I get a `Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'` error on the method

```
override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
}
```

where `var itemAttributes` is an  `NSMutableArray!`

The error is being generated by the second index, `[indexPath.row]`.

Any ideas?  I've tried putting the same function in a swift playground and did not get any errors..

Updated! [This](http://swiftstub.com/244420487/?v=gm) is a swiftstub w/ my playground saved in it.  It doesn't execute because of the `Import UIKit`, but the following:

```
let x = collectionViewLayout.itemAttributes[indexPath.section]
let y = collectionViewLayout.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
print( "x's type = \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(x))")
print("x = \(x)")
print( "y's type = \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(y))")
print("y = \(y)")
```

yields:

```
x's type = __NSArrayM
x = (
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ac041d0> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); frame = (0 0; 66 30); zIndex = 1024; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ac05030> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}); frame = (65 0; 63 30); zIndex = 1023; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ae1e2a0> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}); frame = (127 0; 65 30); zIndex = 1023; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ac06830> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}); frame = (191 0; 66 30); zIndex = 1023; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ae21e50> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}); frame = (256 0; 67 30); zIndex = 1023; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ad70f30> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}); frame = (322 0; 66 30); zIndex = 1023; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ac054e0> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}); frame = (387 0; 66 30); zIndex = 1023; ",
    "<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ad72420> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000e00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}); frame = (452 0; 65 30); zIndex = 1023; "
)
y's type = Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>
y = <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fbe6ac041d0> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); frame = (0 0; 66 30); zIndex = 1024;
```

Comment: If you save `self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section]` into a variable, what does Swift think its type is?

Comment: @PhillipMills I updated my question.  Is it not strange that this works in a playground but won't compile in my editor?

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: I have the same error too. Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Xcode 7 beta-4 @codecowboy

Comment: @ SebastienHareng I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change `override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` to

`override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let x : NSMutableArray = self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section] as! NSMutableArray
    let l = x[row] as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    return l
}`

I'll fork CustomCollectionLayoutView later today and make a swift2 copy

Comment: Please can you add an explanation of why this fixes it?